# Radium-React reports "please wrap your application in the StyleRoot component" when using MediaQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radium

This is how my component looks like

```
import React from "react";
import Radium from "radium";
import StyleRoot from "radium";

var styles = {

    base: {
        background: 'blue',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 4,
        color: 'white',
        padding: '1.5em',
        width: '15%',

        '@media (min-width: 320px)': {
            width: '100%'
        },

        ':hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        },

        ':focus': {
            backgroundColor: 'green'
        },

        ':active': {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        },
    },

    block: {
        display: 'block',

        ':hover': {
            boxShadow: '0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
        }
    },
};

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <StyleRoot>
                <button style={[
                    styles.base,
                    this.props.block && styles.block
                ]}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </button>
            </StyleRoot>
        );
    }
}

// https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/816
// https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/455
export default Radium(LoginPage);
```

My `package.json` entry looks like

```
"radium": "^0.19.1",
```

I even tried with the following import

```
import {StyleRoot} from "radium";
```

But the error remained same. The entire stacktrace looks like

```
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
getClosestInstanceFromNode @ ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113
findParent @ ReactEventListener.js:38
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js:67
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$l955y3wpg6n' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
```

What have I missed in following the steps?

Answer (score 0):

It says "wrap your application" because the `StyleRoot` needs to exist before the `Radium` function is called:

```
let Wrapper = ({ children }) => <StyleRoot>{children}</StyleRoot>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper><LoginPage /></Wrapper>,
  el,
)
```

You probably already have a root level component that is not your LoginPage so you can use that instead of making a new wrapper component.

Also `import {StyleRoot} from 'radium';` is the correct syntax. If you wanted to import both `Radium` and `Styleroot` it would look like:

`import Radium, {StyleRoot} from 'radium';`